# Using a guard to check array length

Tags: javascript

I currently have a function that checks whether an array length is 0 and throws an error if this is the case. I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how to do this with the && operator instead which would perhaps be more of an efficient guard in this case.

```
checkSample function(size) {
  if(size.length === 0) {
    throw new RangeError('Length must be greater than zero');
  }
})
```

Comment: `&&` is a binary operator and checking `size.length` is a unary operation.

Comment: You might do `size.length === 0 && throw...` but it's not more nor less efficient.

Comment: Why would you want to use the `&&` operator?

Comment: There's no need to use `&&` here. `&&` needs expressions as operands, and `throw` is a statement. Arranging `throw` into an expression would take much more time than executing a simple `if`.

Comment: @Teemu Yes, it is a [Binary Logical Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11). Binary just means needs two inputs, not which type of operator (logical or otherwise) it is. My point was that there's nothing to *AND* here (except something like **Kenneys** suggestion but he also acknowledges that it doesn't really have a point)

Comment: @nem Ah... OK, now I understand your comment. Btw. Kenneys suggestion would throw an error, "Expression expected".

Comment: @Lilp `0` is evaluated as a falsy value, hence `if (!size.length)` should be the most efficient check.

Comment: Do you perhaps come from a different language background? Ruby for example lets you do `some_condition && do_something` which works like `if (some_condition) do_something; end`, and is actually preferred over it in the style guide. This does not exist in Javascript however, and really doesn't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why it would be more efficient and why would you optimize this call. I would not do premature optimization and change all checks to that. If it is not bottleneck leave it. Also seems like your way of doing it is really easy to understend where solution with && is weird and would need some comment at least.

```
if(0 && 1){// false and true = false
 alert('true') //0=false, anything else than 0 is true
} else{
 alert('false')
}
```

Gives false.

```
if(500 && 1){ //true and true = true
 alert('true')//so if array length is different than 0 it will evaluate as true
} else{       //that is the way JavaScript works
 alert('false')
}
```

Gives true.

Therfore:

```
  if(size.length && 1) {
    //here your happy flow
  } else
  {
    throw new RangeError('Length must be greater than zero');
  }
```

Comment: The ` && 1` is completely superfluous. `if(size.length && 1)` is exactly equal to `if(size.length)` is all cases. This is like saying `if(expression and true)`. Lilp did ask for && to be used, so I guess that's why you used, it, but Lilp also seemed to think that it would improve efficiency, really this is doing another unnecessary and.

Comment: I have added some comments that would make it more clear that 0 equals false and any number is true.